# (OSMNX, Folium) Plotting and Isochrone on a Folium Web Map

Tags: python, openstreetmap, matplotlib, networkx, folium

I am trying to plot an isochrone map like the one in [this](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb) example onto a Folium Web Map.

I understand how to set up the colors for time/edges/nodes/polygons... I just don't understand how I could get any of that onto a Folium map...

I am having trouble understanding which object(s) to pass into the following two functions:

```
osmnx.plot.plot_route_folium() 
osmnx.plot.plot_graph_folium()
```

My code, currently, is simply following the above cited example, but I an stuck on how to incorporate Folium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSMnx does not have functionality to plot isochrones on a folium web map: see the documentation for [plotting a graph with folium](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_graph_folium) and for [plotting a route with folium](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_route_folium). Beyond that, you could write your own code to extend this functionality.

Comment: Shapes can be added to folium maps using m = folium.Map(); folium.GeoJson(gj).add_to(m). So if the isochrone shapes can be projected back to latlong, would that work?

Comment: Sounds like it - worth a try.